# Resize UITableViewCell by gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to resize an individual UITableViewCell when the user pinches it. When the 'pinch' is big enough I want to perform a segue.

So in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I alloc/init an UIPinchGestureRecognizer and attach it to the cell.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

       /** adding info to the cell **/ 

       UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(makeBiggerCell:)];
       [cell addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
       return cell;
}
```

In the following method, I wanted to calculate (and set) a height for a selected row based on the user's gesture and 'redraw' it. Like I said, if the gesture finishes and the cell is big enough then I want to perform a segue.

```
- (void)makeBiggerCell:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

      if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){

          // I have a private property of NSIndexPath in order to keep 
          // track of the selected row.
          self.selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender.view];

         CGPoint windowPoint = [gesture locationOfTouch:1 inView:nil];
         CGPoint tablePoint =  [gesture locationInView:self.tableView];


         self.sizeOfCell = fabsf(tablePoint.y - windowPoint.y);

         // the MINIMUM_CELL_SIZE is the regular size of the cell 
         // this conditional tries to avoid small tableviewcells
         // IMPORTANT: as long as the user keeps his fingers on the cell 
         // the 'resize' happens

         if (self.sizeOfCell > MINIMUM_CELL_SIZE)
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

     }else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

         if (sender.scale >=5) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender.view];
         }
      }

}
```

Finally the place where I set the height for a selected row

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      if (self.selectedIndexPath && self.selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row && self.sizeOfCell) 
          return self.sizeOfCell + MINIMUM_CELL_SIZE; 
else 
         return MINIMUM_CELL_SIZE;
  }
```

**The problem besides of having the 2 properties (sizeOfCell and selectedIndexPath)**  is the appearance of changing the uitableviewcell size, doesnt look 'smooth' enough. I want to achieve something similar like the iOS 7 weather app, when you pinch a cell and perform a segue.

If you guys have a cleaner solution for my problem I would be sooo thankful! :]

Answer (score 0):

Just to recommend something for you to try... not sure if it will give you smooth result.... try using pinchGesture's scale to set the size, and set the scale back to 1 after each change.

```
if (pinchGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || pinchGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) { 
    self.sizeOfCell.width *= pinchGesture.scale; 
    self.sizeOfCell.height *= pinchGesture.scale; 
    pinchGesture.scale = 1; 
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: @[self.selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
}
```

Your performSegue should be called in setter of the @property sizeOfCell, checking when the it's larger than 5 and performSegue.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! You were right. Although the effect is not as smooth as I would expect it works fine.